# turtle graphics: starting a new line

Tags: c++, opencv, turtle-graphics

Sorry for the massive block of code ;w;

I'm learning C++, and this is an assignment I'm stuck on- I'm supposed to be making a brick wall with alternating rows offset by 1/2 bricks, and I'm supposed to be using a nested loop to do so.

I've got the functions to draw the full brick and half bricks, and I've successfully been able to create a full line of 9 bricks(9 being how many bricks can span the window) and I'm stuck on the next step. I need to make the program draw the next line after the first one is finished, but "\n" and "cout << endl;" only affect the main window and not the "TurtleWindow" that OpenCV opens. All I have in that regard is that it has something to do with the "changePosition" command, but I'm not sure how to add that in to my loop. If I set position to some specific (x, y) coords, then wouldn't it just keep setting the "bricks" in that position every loop?

Any help would be appreciated, I feel like I'm so close to the solution but this is stumping me...

```
// BrickWall.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins
//and ends there.
//
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#define M_PI   3.14159265358979323846264338327950288
#define degToRad(angleInDegrees) ((angleInDegrees) * M_PI / 180.0)

char wndname[] = "TurtleWindow";

Mat image = Mat::zeros(500, 500, CV_8UC3);
Scalar WHITE(255, 255, 255);
const int DELAY = 1;
Point _curPosition(250, 250);
int _direction = 0;

void init()
{
    imshow(wndname, image);
    waitKey(DELAY);
}
//
// Move the pen to the given coordinates without leaving a mark
// 
// Note (0,0)     refers to the upper left corner
//      (500,500) refers to the bottom right corner  
//
void changePosition(int x, int y)
{
    _curPosition.x = x;
    _curPosition.y = y;
}
//
// point in the direction given in degrees
// 0   ==> point right
// 90  ==> point down
// 180 ==> point left
// 270 ==> point up
//
void changeDirection(int direction)
{
    _direction = direction;
}
//
// Moves the pen forward the given number of pixels
// Note leaves a mark creating a line from the previous point
// to the new point
//
void moveForward(int nPixels)
{
    int x = static_cast<int>(round(nPixels * cos(degToRad(_direction))));
    int y = static_cast<int>(round(nPixels * sin(degToRad(_direction))));
    Point newPoint = Point(x + _curPosition.x, y + _curPosition.y);
    line(image, _curPosition, newPoint, WHITE);
    _curPosition = newPoint;
    // cout << "moved to " << newPoint.x << "," << newPoint.y << endl;
    imshow(wndname, image);
    waitKey(DELAY);
}

void fullBrick()
//  changePosition(25, 25);
{
    changeDirection(0);
    moveForward(50);
    changeDirection(90);
    moveForward(20);
    changeDirection(180);
    moveForward(50);
    changeDirection(270);
    moveForward(20);
    changeDirection(0);
    moveForward(50);
}
void halfBrick()
//changePosition(25, 45);
{
    changeDirection(0);
    moveForward(25);
    changeDirection(90);
    moveForward(20);
    changeDirection(180);
    moveForward(25);
    changeDirection(270);
    moveForward(20);
}

int main()
{
    int counter;
    int counterWall;
    counterWall = 0;
    counter = 0;
    init();

    changePosition(25, 25);
    while (counter < 20)
    {
            do
            {
                changeDirection(0);
                moveForward(50);
                changeDirection(90);
                moveForward(20);
                changeDirection(180);
                moveForward(50);
                changeDirection(270);
                moveForward(20);
                changeDirection(0);
                moveForward(50);
                counterWall++;
            } while (counterWall < 9);
            counter++;
    }
    waitKey();
}
```

edit: thanks everyone for the advice! I was fully intending to use a nested loop in the end(and did use one, so no lost points there!) and was able to realize there was nothing stopping me from looping the bricks like a snake. I had to turn the assignment in before I could try any of the changes you guys offered, but I'll be sure to keep them in mind for future assignments!

and here's a link to the picture of the final product, I've never been happier to see a brick wall in my life
[Brick Wall Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jktbh.png)

Comment: pictures or vacate the premises ;) *try* things if you think they might get you closer to the solution. you don't need to be sure. wrong paths don't cost you anything but typing and time.

Comment: I would recommend that you follow the teacher's advice and use *nested loops* (and for-loops at that), one for the rows, one for the bricks in a row. and *use* the brick functions you defined. if you don't use them, they just sit there and do nothing.

Comment: learn about for loops, that way you dont need to declare a counter, at least not in another previous line